Scene 3D objects throw exception on Android deivces
I posted a thread some time ago about Scene 3D objects causing a error when they try to create the shader on Android.  At the time I was advised to recompile the project using the new Gluon library rather than JavaFXPorts.  I have now done this but the result is not compatible with my device.  I have found that the Gluon project works fine on a Motorola device running Android 13 and the JavaFXPorts project works on an old Samsung device running Android 4.4.2.  However the Gluon project won't even install on my intended target device, which is an MBOX running Android 6.0.1, but the JavaFXPorts project installs fine but throws 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating shader program' on the MBOX.  I have found that the MBOX will run projects not containing any 3D objects, for example the two sample projects included in the Dalvik SDK - Ensemble8 and HelloAndroid - work fine.  I have also tried printing out the result of Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D) but confusingly this shows true despite the error.  Is there any way around this using the JavaFXPorts technology as this has produced the best results?  When I try to do a push install to  the MBOX using ADB it gives an error of 'Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]'.  My searches online indicate that this may be due to the version of the NDK it was compiled with but I have found that the project only seems to compile with the Android 21 NDK.

The package you're trying to install is lacking the native assembly for whatever CPU architecture that "MBOX" has, whatever an "MBOX" may be ...it is supposed to be aarch64, while arm32 is not being provided (anymore): https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
